# How to sum multiple dimensions

Tags: javascript, json, crossfilter

I'm just starting out with Crossfilter and am trying to understand how some of the reduction functions work. I thought it made sense to me and tried to build a small examples based on the sample data but I can't seem to get it working.

What I'm trying to do, is sum multiple columns to get their totals (e.g. total and tip) based on a field (e.g. type). Now I'm not sure how I do this with multiple columns, but actually what I've found is the approach I've taken doesn't even seem to work with a single column.

I've put together a short snippet and what I expected from the output was 3 rows showing the summed total for `tab`, `visa` and `cash`.

```js
var payments = crossfilter([
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:28:54Z", quantity: 1, total: 300, tip: 200, type: "visa"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:30:43Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:48:46Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:53:41Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:54:06Z", quantity: 1, total: 100, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T16:58:03Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:07:21Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:22:59Z", quantity: 2, total: 90, tip: 0, type: "tab"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:25:45Z", quantity: 2, total: 200, tip: 0, type: "cash"},
  {date: "2011-11-14T17:29:52Z", quantity: 1, total: 200, tip: 100, type: "visa"}
]);

var typeDimension = payments.dimension(function(d) { return d.type; });
typeDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.total; });

$(typeDimension.top(Infinity)).each(function(d) { 
     $('#tgt').append("<div>" + JSON.stringify(this) + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crossfilter/1.3.11/crossfilter.min.js"></script>
<div id="tgt">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

To explain my use case a little better - I've actually got some different data, about 10k rows of the following format:

```
{ athlete: "Michael Phelps",age:23,country:"United States",year:2008,date: 39684,sport:"Swimming",gold:8,silver:0,bronze:0,total: 8 },
{ athlete: "Michael Phelps",age:19,country:"United States",year:2004,date: 38228,sport:"Swimming",gold:6,silver:0,bronze:2,total: 8 },
{ athlete: "Michael Phelps",age:27,country:"United States",year:2012,date: 41133,sport:"Swimming",gold:4,silver:2,bronze:0,total: 6 },
```

What I want to do is group the bronze, silver and gold values across years, so I can see the total number of medals given out in each year so I can display them properly. At the moment the graphing library that I'm using can't handle the data when not grouped, the following picture illustrates this with shaded bands on each bar because there are hundreds of little shaded rectangles building up each stack.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript SQL library as alternative to CrossFilter (of course, if using of CrossFilter is not critical for your porject) to sum multiple dimensions.

```
var data = [
   {date: "2011-11-14T16:17:54Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"},
   {date: "2011-11-14T16:20:19Z", quantity: 2, total: 190, tip: 100, type: "tab"}];

var res = alasql('SELECT type, SUM(quantity) quantity AS , SUM(total) AS total, \
             SUM(tip) AS tip FROM ? GROUP BY type', [data]);
```

Try this sample [at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/ncqcb8o2/1/). Or another example of [Alasql+d3.js integration](http://alasql.org/demo/005d3) with sum by multiple dimension.

By the way, Alasql is faster than CrossFilter on these data (see [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/alasql-vs-crossfilter)).

Sorry, for 'non-CrossFilter' answer.

Comment: That's actually useful - I'm not currently limited to cross filter, just need something that will allow me to build an inter-connected dashboard. I'll take a look at this too, thanks.

Comment: I would note, that your mentioned about performance - I'm actually using a much bigger dataset. The sample posted is the crossfilter example, for testing I'm actually using data from here http://www.tableausoftware.com/public/sites/default/files/OlympicAthletes_0.xlsx

Comment: I will check it tonight. To load data from XLSX you can use: var res = alasql("SELECT Country, SUM([Gold Medals]) AS [Gold Medals] FROM XLSX('data.xlsx', {headers:true, sheetid:'OlympicAtletes'}) GROUP BY Country");   To read XLSX file you need to add XLSX.js library (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) into you file

Comment: I've got a JSON file - have never used JSPerf before but I'm just trying to put a test together now - just missing something somewhere

Comment: Managed to work it out - http://jsperf.com/alasql-vs-crossfilter-athletic-data suggests Alasql is faster on this dataset too. Nice work :) Interesting if you compare in IE though, complete reversal of the results.

Comment: Thank you for the test! I also test on other browsers: Alasql gives comparable result vs CrossFilter on WebKit, and loose on Firefox and IE. Good point to start an optimization.

Comment: No worries - I'm actually testing across different browsers now to compare (emulation mode in IE). Out of curiosity are you aware of anyone building dashboards with Alasql? Or using D3js with it? As a word of note - I'd also consider putting a disclaimer on your answer to state you're the creator of Alasql to be clear to the community.

Comment: 1. The disclaimer: yes, of course (sorry, I didn't mentioned it in my answer). 2. Dashboards - not yet, but I will be happy to support any activity in this direction (if you are interested we can talk on this by email).

Comment: Sure - I'm going to try building an example interconnected dashboard and see how I get on. I'd like to continue this in crossfilter and then I'll compare to Alasql. I'm happy to share my findings with you especially if you're up for trying to make that task easier. Is your email some combination of your username & gmail?

Comment: I.e. login like here at gmail

Comment: Does Alasql do incremental/coordinated updates of queries? If not, it seems a bit odd to compare its performance to Crossfilter. If someone doesn't need coordinated updates then I don't see Crossfilter as a great option in general.

Comment: No. Every query is "solid" (like SQL does) and Alasql recalculates it from very beginning (except compilation: Alasql stores result of parsing and compilation of SQL statement to the cache, because it is a relatively slow operation, and also it stores prepared indexes). I aabsolutly agree with you, that incremental update is a strong feature of CrossFilter, but it does not used even on fromt-page demo